# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Tags: php, mysql

actualmente estoy aprendiendo a programar en PHP por unos tutoriales en Youtube de "the newboston" (tal vez lo conozcan) y estoy en la parte de base de datos en mySQL.

En mi programa intento consultar datos de una tabla en mySQL pero me arroja un error que dice lo siguiente: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given.

este es mi codigo:

**Por parte de la plantilla**

```
<?php

$con_error='Could not connect';

$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_pass='';
$mysql_db='new_database';

/*connect to server / database*/
$mysqlcon=@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die($con_error);

/*select database*/
mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $mysqlcon) or die($con_error);
```

**Por parte de la pagina que lo ejecuta**

```
    require 'database.php';

$query="SELECT * FROM comida ORDER BY id";

if ($query_run = @mysql_query($query)) {

    while ($query_run= mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
        $platillo=$query_run['platillo'];
        $calorias=$query_run['calorias'];

        echo ' <br> platillo '.$platillo.' ofrece '.$calorias.'<br>';
    }

} else {
    echo '<br> could not connect <br>';
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto. Gracias de antemano por las respuestas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problema

`mysql_fetch_array()` toma como parámetro el resultado de un `mysql_query()`. Y esto lo estás realizando correctamente para el inicio del bucle. Sin embargo, estás sobreescribiendo el valor de `$query_run`, por lo que en la segunda iteración del bucle, no tendrá el valor del resultado del query.

Es decir, para la primera fila que recuperás con el query, se ejecuta correctamente:

```
while ($query_run= mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
```

Pero nótese que se le asigna un nuevo valor a `$query_run`.
En consecuencia, para la segunda fila, cuando se ejecuta:

```
while ($query_run= mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Ya no tiene el resultado de `mysql_query()`

#### Solución

Utilizar una variable diferente para el resultado de `mysql_fetch_array()`. Usemos `$fila` por ejemplo:

```
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    $platillo=$fila['platillo'];
    $calorias=$fila['calorias'];

    echo ' <br> platillo '.$platillo.' ofrece '.$calorias.'<br>';
}
```

#### Nota de Seguridad

Aparentemente el tutorial que estás viendo ha quedado un poco desactualizado. Las funciones `mysql_*` han quedado obsoletas y presentan problemas de seguridad. Es muy importante que leas el artículo [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127) para ver cómo implementar esto mismo correctamente.

Comment: Tienes razon, ya me compila de manera correcta. Gracias!

Comment: @INME Me alegro que te haya sido útil. Sin embargo, por favor lee la nota de seguridad. Si bien no afecta directamente al código que estás utilizando, mejor empezar a codificar con el pie derecho... Las funciones `mysql_*` van a dejar de existir eventualmente.

Comment: Orale, gracias por el dato para evitar esos conflictos de seguridad que a nadie le gustan jeje, gracias